# Extracting Datetime

Tags: sql, datetime

I have a column of `Datetime2(7)` I want to extract datetime from that column. I wrote the following query

```
select*
from tablename
where columnname>= '2001-01-30';
```

It does extract date for that particular datetime.

But I want to extract date from a particular date to a particular date. It then gives me an error that `string cant be converted to datetime`. Whereas the datatype is `Datetime2(7)`.

Answer (score 0):

Try converting the column to a date

**[SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/fface/1)**

```
select * 
from YourTable 
where cast(columnName as date) = '2001-01-30'
```

Comment: Hey Thanks for the help, but my data is already in date format. So would using cast help ?